# Joomla php - load if not loaded

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla site. Bootstrap grip.css is loaded from a component. 
But on pages where the component is not used the css file is not loaded and i need it to for styling.

How do create a code strip with  IF not loaded then load /file in my index.php?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to test whether a CSS file is loaded but you could use `unset` to unload `grip.css` (see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4986/120 for details) and then use `addStyleSheet` or similar to load `grip.css` (see https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page for details).

Using this method can ensure `grip.css` is loaded exactly once on each page.